# ng-show and ng-hide are slow in Ionic. Two elements visible for few ms (only in iOS)

Tags: javascript, ios, css, angularjs, ionic-framework

In an Ionic project I have an audio player. If audio is not playing user can:

1. user tap play button
2. audio starts
3. play button is hidden and pause button is shown

And in just the opposite, if audio is playing user can:

1. user tap pause button
2. audio is paused
3. pause button is hidden and play button is shown

The issue is that **for a few ms both play and pause are shown**. It only happens when I tap pause button (when audio is playing) and only with iOS, in android I don't have this problem.

This is how error looks:

[image]

The buttons html is:

```
<span ng-click="player.playAudio(audio)" ng-hide="player.isViewAudioPlayingAudio()">
    <img src="img/audio-play-icon.svg" alt="" class="big-icon audio-control">
    <img src="img/audio-play-hover-icon.svg" alt="" class="big-icon audio-control-hover">
</span>

<span ng-click="player.pauseAudio()" ng-show="player.isViewAudioPlayingAudio()">
    <img src="img/audio-pause-icon.svg" alt="" class="big-icon audio-control" >
    <img src="img/audio-pause-hover-icon.svg" alt="" class="big-icon audio-control-hover">
</span>
```

You can see here how classes change (GIF image, click to open it)

[image]

For hover buttons I have few lines of CSS. This is not the problem, I tried without hover images and I still have the issue, but I show you for clarify.

```
.audio-control-hover{
    display: none;
}

.activated{
    .audio-control{
        display: none;
    }

    .audio-control-hover{
        display: inline;
    }
}
```

**Any idea how to improve performance of ng-show and ng-hide?**

Answer (score 0):

Performance wise ng-if is better for some scenarios. This is a good article about it. Try with a ng-if instead and see it will improve it.

http://www.codelord.net/2015/07/28/angular-performance-ng-show-vs-ng-if/

Answer (score 0):

Ionic is using angular js animate library to apply certain transitions from one state to another. It doesnt work well on iOS. Try adding below code to your css to surpress animation:

```
.ng-hide,
.ng-animate,
.ng-hide-animate,
.ng-hide-remove {
    display: none !important;
}

.ng-animate.no-animate {
    -webkit-transition: 0s none;
            transition: 0s none;
     -webkit-animation: 0s none;
             animation: 0s none;
}
```

I hope it helps :)